# Can I say "We sell sea food by the weight of the item?" in a restaurant?

Tags: word-choice

In my restaurant, we sell seafood this way: if you choose a big fish and it weighs 1.5 kilograms, you only have to pay for 1.5 kilo of that fish and  don't have to buy more or less. I mean you don't have to do that to round up or round down the weight of the item, you don't have to buy exactly 1 kilo or 2 kilos. So in this case, can I say "We sell seafood by the weight of the item?"

Comment: I imagine that the fish is weighed in front of the customer? Is that so? Are we talking about lobsters, crabs, for instance? Or does it include also non-shellfish, e.g. octopus (something I would expect to *see* it in a seafood menu)

Comment: @ Mari-Lou A, yes the fish is weighted in front of the customer and we're talking about creatures that weigh over 1 kilo, so that include some big non-shellfish as well.

Comment: If I were to see a sign that says "we sell seafood by the weight" in a *restaurant*, I would understand. I don't think adding "of the item" is necessary, it's implied in the claim.

Comment: @Mari-LouA thank you Mari, your answer cleared my doubt.

Comment: You probably will get better answers from Americans, I know shellfish restaurants are big in the States, and the protocol you described is not uncommon. It's very likely that there's a typical catchphrase, which restaurants use, I don't know what it might be.

Comment: It is unclear what precisely is being asked here. If one sells something by weight, *of course*, one may, and should, say that one sells it by weight. What is the reason for doubting it?

Answer (score 1):

It’s idiomatic to say that you sell the seafood *by weight*.

> **by weight**
>   as determined by weighing
>   [- Collins](https://www.google.com.au/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/by-weight)

Here are a couple of examples from the web:

- Selling Products by Weight or Length
  [- Nextar](http://help.nextar.com/tutorial/register-product-to-sell-it-fractionally)
- If you are buying or selling seafood by weight, you need to know about Australia’s trade measurement laws.
  [- National Measurement Institute, Trade Measurement and the Sale of Seafood](http://www.measurement.gov.au/Publications/FactSheets/Documents/Trade-Measurement-and-the-Sale-of-Seafood.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

> Can I say "We sell seafood by the weight of the item?"

It seems reasonable, you don't want to cut an estimated bit off and add a bit back to make some exact weight, you want to sell one whole item, whatever it weighs, for however much per kilogram.

If you were selling eggs you only want to sell whole eggs, not non-integer quantities.

What you need to be careful with is standard industry practice and [the law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seafood_mislabelling#Overstating_quantities) in your area.

Sometimes terms like "individually measured" are used, other times it's "[catch-weight](https://findlayfoods.com/what-is-catch-weight)".